# Google Container Engine New cluster appears to have failed

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I tried to create a new cluster in Container Engine in the Google Developers Console.

It finished pretty quickly with a yellow triangle with an exclamation point. I'm assuming that means it didn't work.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you deleted your default network?

The alpha version of Container Engine relies on the default network when creating VMs and routes between the nodes and you will see an error creating a cluster if you have deleted the default network.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few things that could go wrong. The best option to figure out what's wrong in your situation is to try using the gcloud command line tool, which gives better error information. Information about how to install and use it is in [Container Engine's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/before-you-begin#install_the_gcloud_command_line_interface).

Other than the default network being removed (as mentioned by Robert Bailey), you may be trying to create more VM instances than you have quota for. You can check what your quota is on the developer console under Compute > Compute Engine > Quota. You're most likely to go over quota on either CPUs or in-use IP addresses, since each VM created is given an ephemeral IP address.